# Serve static content through NGINX, based on subdomain name

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to improve the page speed of a site I run by serving static content directly from NGINX rather than the request hitting PHP.

I have webpages at paths like this:

- gamea.com.mysite.com
- anotherb.net.mysite.com
- finalc.org.mysite.com

When a page is generated for these, it's stored in a path like this:

- /storage/app/page-cache/games/game/gamea_com/1.c
- /storage/app/page-cache/games/anot/anotherb_net/1.c
- /storage/app/page-cache/games/fina/finalc_org/1.c

The path structure takes the first 4 letters of the subdomain, and then follows by another folder with the full path and replaces "." with "_" - e.g. "gamea.com" = "/game/gamea_com/". The actual cache page file is stored as "1.c"

How might this be accomplished through NGINX? I'm a bit stuck, I did find [this article](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-multi-tenancy) but I'm unsure how to use it in my case - can anyone provide an example NGINX config that points NGINX to the correct path as described above?

I thank you whoever can help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to capture the three parts of the subdomain using a regular expression, then paste them into a `root` statement. Use named captures as the numeric captures may be out of scope where they are evaluated. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name  "~^(?<name1>.{4})(?<name2>.*)\.(?<name3>.*)\.example\.com$";
    root /path/to/root/$name1/$name1$name2_$name3;
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, decode the `$http_host` variable using a `map`. The regular expression is the same, and the result could be used in a `root` or `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
map $http_host $mypath {
    default                                                     "nonexistent";
    "~^(?<name1>.{4})(?<name2>.*)\.(?<name3>.*)\.example\.com$" $name1/$name1$name2_$name3;
}
server {
    ...
    root /path/to/root;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /$mypath$uri =404;
    }
}
```

---

You can split the `try_files` across two `location` blocks with:

```
root /path/to/root;
location / {
    try_files $uri @other;
}
location @other {
    try_files /$mypath$uri =404;
}
```

Swap the terms depending on which files you want Nginx to look for first. Use `add_header` statements in either `location` to customise the appropriate response. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details. 
Either `location` can contain specific headers

Comment: Hmm... how would I set the path to the file, including extracting only 4 letters for the part of the path that is limited to 4 letters, e.g. "fina" in "/fina/finalc_org/1.c" ?

Comment: `$name1` should capture the first 4 letters (e.g. "fina"), and `$name3` captures anything after the `.` (e.g. "org, and `$name2` captures the bit between (e.g. "lc").

Comment: Also, I fixed a couple of errors in the `root` statement.

Comment: Mainly I was thinking I could use a "location / {" location block with "try_files" instead of needing another server {} block?

Comment: You could use a `map` and evaluate it with a `try_files` statement.

Comment: Richard, would you mind showing how to do that by adding to your answer above? I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: I've finally begun to implement this and I've managed to get the map working with your example, however, I'd like to know how to add headers when try_files determines that $mypath is found? My cached html files should return some custom headers, such as the content type and expiry, among other headers. I tried location /$mypath {} but that doesn't work.